# New iMac is set to English but Chinese appears sporadically in settings

Tags: imac, language

I received a new iMac today purchased from the Apple website. I set the language on initial setup to English. However, I noticed that the output sound device had a name in Chinese and even when I went to install the latest updates, the TOS to accept was in Chinese. I read online that using `sudo languagesetup` would fix the issue, but I'm more interested in how and why this happened in the first place. The computer was sent directly from China, how do I know there isn't some modified version of MacOS installed? Any information and opinions would be greatly appreciated.

Here are a few screenshots. Note the name out of the output device as well:
[image]

English and Finnish are selected (I am in Finland):
[image]

Comment: In my experience it's not uncommon to see reports of mixed localization glitches like this in Apple's discussion forums. As far as I know, there's no explanation for them, nor do they signal anything sinister.

Comment: Try to reset nvram/pram as there may be some scories due to factory testing.